# Mac App - Using a search engine without opening it

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am building a Mac application that will prompt the user to ask a question.
I want my app to search the question on Google in the background without actually opening the browser. How can I do this?

Comment: So the main feature of your application is leting the user make an internet query in background.  And your question is 'How can I do this'?  And you are not even showing a single line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could query google custom search:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={YOU_API_KEY}&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures"];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *resp;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] returningResponse:&resp error:nil];
        if(resp.statusCode == 200) {
            id results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            if(results) {
                NSLog(@"%@", results);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

see: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

Comment: note that it is only free for < 100 requests per day.